# How to pass variable from javascript to google sheet web app

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, web-applications

So I have 5 questions with dropdowns. Dropdown has 1-5 options. I stored their selections for each question as an array but I'm not sure how to save them in my Google sheets. I'm definitely new in creating google web apps. Any help is highly appreciated.

**html**

```html
  <p>1. Question no 1. Rate from 1 -5</p>       
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <select id="1_kscore" class="form-control kscore" name="Value[]" style="font-size:8pt">
                  <option selected>NA</option>
                  <? for(var i = 0; i < dd_score.length; i++) { ?>      
                <option value="<?= dd_score[i] ?>" ><?= dd_score[i] ?></option>
              <? } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div> <!--- close row -->

          <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:8px">
            <div class="col-10">
              <p>2. Question no 2. Rate from 1 -5   </p>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <select id="2_kscore" class="form-control kscore" name="Value[]" style="font-size:8pt">
                  <option selected>NA</option>
                  <? for(var i = 0; i < dd_score.length; i++) { ?>      
                <option value="<?= dd_score[i] ?>" ><?= dd_score[i] ?></option>
              <? } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div> <!--- close row -->
```

*and so on...*

**code.gs**

```
function writeArray(c_score){

var sh1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
var lR = sh1.getLastRow() + 1;
sh1.getRange(lR,1,1,5).setValues([c_score]);

}
```

**javascript**

```js
function submit(){

  c_selects = document.getElementsByClassName("cscore");
  for(var i=0;i<c_selects.length;i++){
    c_score = c_selects[i].value;
    alert(c_score);
    google.script.run.writeArray(c_score);  

  }  
}
```

variable c_score are the scores for each 5 questions I have w/c for example are 5,5,4,5,5

Comment: [client to server communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Aren't your options always NA and the numbers 1 to 5?  And why is `writeArray` in a loop?  You have no way of knowing in which order they are executed in sheet.  `google.script.run` is an asynchronous process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

I've put together a sample dialog and script that will get the scores and place them in a spreadsheet.

**HTML_Score.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:8px">
      <div class="col-10">
        <p>1. Question no 1. Rate from 1 -5</p>       
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <select id="1_kscore" class="form-control kscore" name="Value[]" style="font-size:8pt">
          <option selected>NA</option>
          <? for(var i = 0; i < dd_score.length; i++) { ?>      
            <option value="<?= dd_score[i] ?>" ><?= dd_score[i] ?></option>
          <? } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div> <!--- close row -->

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:8px">
      <div class="col-10">
        <p>2. Question no 2. Rate from 1 -5   </p>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <select id="2_kscore" class="form-control kscore" name="Value[]" style="font-size:8pt">
          <option selected>NA</option>
          <? for(var i = 0; i < dd_score.length; i++) { ?>      
            <option value="<?= dd_score[i] ?>" ><?= dd_score[i] ?></option>
          <? } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div> <!--- close row -->

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:8px">
      <div class="col-10">
        <p>2. Question no 3. Rate from 1 -5   </p>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <select id="2_kscore" class="form-control kscore" name="Value[]" style="font-size:8pt">
          <option selected>NA</option>
          <? for(var i = 0; i < dd_score.length; i++) { ?>      
            <option value="<?= dd_score[i] ?>" ><?= dd_score[i] ?></option>
          <? } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div> <!--- close row -->

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:8px">
      <div class="col-10">
        <p>2. Question no 4. Rate from 1 -5   </p>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <select id="2_kscore" class="form-control kscore" name="Value[]" style="font-size:8pt">
          <option selected>NA</option>
          <? for(var i = 0; i < dd_score.length; i++) { ?>      
            <option value="<?= dd_score[i] ?>" ><?= dd_score[i] ?></option>
          <? } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div> <!--- close row -->

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:8px">
      <div class="col-10">
        <p>2. Question no 5. Rate from 1 -5   </p>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <select id="2_kscore" class="form-control kscore" name="Value[]" style="font-size:8pt">
          <option selected>NA</option>
          <? for(var i = 0; i < dd_score.length; i++) { ?>      
            <option value="<?= dd_score[i] ?>" ><?= dd_score[i] ?></option>
          <? } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div> <!--- close row -->    

    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
    </div>   
    <?!= include('JS_Score'); ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS_Score.html**

```
<script>
  function submit() {
    try {
      let scores = document.getElementsByClassName("kscore");
      let values = [];
      for( let i=0; i<scores.length; i++ ) {
        values.push([scores[i].value]);
      }
      google.script.run.writeArray(values);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function showTest() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  let dd_score = sheet.getRange(1,1,5,1).getValues().flat();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Score");
  html.dd_score = dd_score;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(),"Test");
}

function writeArray(scores) {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    sheet.getRange(1,3,5,1).setValues(scores);  // Put in column C
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Dialog**

[image]

[image]

**Modified scripts for comments below:**

```
<script>
  function submit() {
    try {
      let scores = document.getElementsByClassName("kscore");
      let values = [];
      for( let i=0; i<scores.length; i++ ) {
        values.push(scores[i].value);  // <- create a row
      }
      google.script.run.writeArray(values);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
</script>

function writeArray(scores) {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5).setValues([scores]);  // Put in range An:En (n = new row)
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much TheWizEd it's working. but i am struggling to write the values in a way that the next score will be recorded in the next column rather than the next row

Comment: What do you mean by next row? I don't understand your question.  Right now the score is placed in column C.   Or do you mean if someone else answers the questions the results should go to column D, then E, etc?

Comment: yes that is. so instead of the scores being written in C1:C6, it will be written in A2:E2

Comment: Then A3:E3, then A4:E4, etc?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I've edited my scripts to put values in a row.

Comment: WAHHH... I can't thank you enough! it is perfectly working  you are a genius!